# Filtering queries with same PK but different value keys

Tags: mysql, filter, subquery

I have the following data

```
123    Amy    Sleep
234    Bob    Sleep
987    Helen    Sleep
123    Amy    Awake
123    Amy    Awake
678    Fay    Awake
765    Jay    Awake
876    Irene    Awake
987    Helen    Awake
```

from running

```
SELECT t1.sid, name, status
FROM t2
JOIN Apply ON t2.sid=t1.sid
WHERE status='Awake' OR status='Sleep'
```

1. What would I do so that I can filter and have a unique tuples of the people who is both sleep and Awake? E.g: Amy and Helen.
2. How would I get the tuples of the people that is only asleep/awake?

Comment: APPLY doesn't exist in mysql.

Comment: woops forgot to change that. apply was my old table name hhaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation is one way to find people who are both awake and asleep:

```
SELECT sid, name
FROM yourTable
WHERE status IN ('Sleep', 'Awake')
GROUP BY sid, name
HAVING MIN(status) <> MAX(status);
```

[image]

### Demo

We can try something similar to find persons with only one status:

```
SELECT sid, name
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY sid, name
HAVING MIN(status) = MAX(status);
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: In the second part, it display the people with one status but for both status. If I were to do that but for people that are only awake (no Bob) how would I filter that?

Comment: @user10416282 Use this having clause with my second query: `HAVING MIN(status) = MAX(status) AND MIN(status) = 'Awake'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`

The GROUP BY statement is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
    SELECT sid, name
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE status IN ('Sleep', 'Awake')
    GROUP BY sid, name
    having(distinct status)=2
```